# Bash script not exiting with "exit" without subshells (I think)

Tags: bash, shell, exit

I'm using `stow` to manage my dotfiles and I'm writing a script that can set up my pc and packages automatically. I have all my config files in a `config` folder and that's the stow folder. What I'm basically doing is get the names of all folders (packages) in that folder and stowing them to my home directory. I also have a function that simply tells me if there was an error and exits the script.

I'm running this script on Arch Linux, recently installed, on the tty (I haven't installed a window manager yet). And when it goes to stow bash, it fails because `.bashrc` already exists in home. It gives me the error message, but it doesn't exit and I can't find the reason. I don't think I'm running the `error` function on a subshell like I've seen from other people with this problem, unless there's something I'm missing here...

Here's the function:

```
error () {
    echo "!! ${1} !!"
    exit 1
}
```

And then later on I have something like this:

```
ls -1 config | while read line; do
    stow -d config -t ~ -R "${line}" || error "Failed to stow ${line}."
done
```

Here's the whole code from the creation of the function to the stowing:

```
step () {
    echo "> ${1}"
}

substep () {
    echo "--> ${1}"
}

error () {
    echo "!! ${1} !!"
    exit 1
}

success () {
    echo "** ${1} **"
}

commandexists () {
    # Check if a command exists
    command -v $1 &> /dev/null
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

pkg-install () {
    pkg="${1:?"Error: pkg parameter unset."}"

    step "${msg_install}: ${pkg}"

    substep "Installing ${pkg} from the Arch Linux Repositories."
    sudo pacman -Sy --noconfirm --needed "$pkg"

    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        substep "Installing ${pkg} from the Arch User Repositories."
        yay -Sy --noconfirm --needed "$pkg" || error "${msg_fail_install}: ${pkg}"
    fi

    success "${msg_success_install}: ${pkg}"
}

# Stop installation if yay is not installed
commandexists yay || error "Yay is not installed! Please install yay and try again."

# stow
pkg-install stow

step "Stowing config files"
ls -1 config | while read line; do
    substep "Stowing ${line}"
    stow -d config -t ~ -R "${line}" || error "Failed to stow ${line}."
done
success "Successfully stowed all config files"
```

As you can see, before stowing it checks if `yay` is installed by checking if the command exists. If not, it gives me an error and exits. When I run this on my other pc that doesn't have `yay` installed, it works as expected. It tells me yay is not installed and stops there. But why does it ignore the `exit` command in the stow part when I run it on the pc that has `yay` installed?

Comment: `a|b` runs `a` and `b` in a subshell. So your `while` loop is actually in a subshell. Compare `true | while true; do exit; done` with `while true; do exit; done`

Comment: Oooh I didn't know that also runs in a subshell. Thank you!

Comment: parsing `ls` is considered bad practice. Here you could do something like `for path in config/*; do stow ... "${path#*/}" ... || error ... ; done` (but remember to check that there is at least one file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, you can keep your `while` loop in the parent shell, while moving the `ls` into a subshell:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    stow -d config -t ~ -R "${line}" || error "Failed to stow ${line}."
done < <(ls -1 config)
```

(Using `IFS=` makes your code work correctly with names that begin or end with whitespace; using `-r` makes it work correctly for names that contain literal backslashes).

---

...but don't do that in practice; [`ls` output is unsuited to programmatic use](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Instead, use a glob:

```
for path in config/*; do
    [[ -e $path || -L $path ]] || continue # detect case where config/ was empty
    file=${path%config/}                   # strip the config/ off the name
    stow -d config -t ~ -R "$file" || error "Failed to stow $file"
done
```

Comment: Thanks! I won't use `ls` for programming then.